# Use array feature in RandomForest without flatten

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

How to use array features in RandomForest without flatten the input?

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

array_feature = np.array([0,0,1])
train_x = np.matrix([[1, 2, array_feature], [3, 4, array_feature] , [1,1, array_feature] ])
train_y = np.array([1,0,1])

clf_rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=2)
clf_rf.fit(train_x, train_y)
```

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

In `sklearn`, most models can only use numerical data, and preprocessing is done separately.  Tree models (in `sklearn`) in particular can only make splits on whether a given feature is less or greater than a given value.  You can either flatten the arrays, or provide some encoding for them, depending on what those arrays represent.

*(Tree models in other packages, and perhaps soon in `sklearn`, can treat categorical variables directly.  Ordinal variables get treated just like continuous ones, and unordered categorical variables can be split into arbitrary bipartitions in CART or cause multiple-arity splits in Quinlan-family trees.  But then still you would need to inform the model that your arrays should be treated as ordinal or unordered categorical or ...)